# Select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

what is the the wrong with this

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT ' + 'word' + ' FROM #Parameter'+ ' WHERE ' + 'Name' + '= ' + 'word search';
EXEC @sql
```

the original select is

```
 SELECT word FROM #Parameter WHERE Name = 'word search'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try escaping the single quotes around the phrase `word search`:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = "SELECT " + "word" + " FROM #Parameter"+ " WHERE " +
                            "Name" + "= " + "'word search'";
EXEC @sql
```

**Update:**

For some reason, most likely utter carelessness, you tagged your question with  MySQL.  In SQL Server you can escape a single quote by doubling it, so this should work:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT ' + 'word' + ' FROM #Parameter'+ ' WHERE ' +
                            'Name' + '= ' + '''word search''';
EXEC @sql
```

Comment: @Chis Why on earth did you tag with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369903/select-statement/38370656#comment64151395_38370025), I writing the query for **SQL Server:**

In your case to add the single quote, you need to add triple single quote around the keyword:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + 'word' + ' FROM #Parameter' + ' WHERE ' +
                            'Name' + ' = ' + '''word search''';
--PRINT @sql
EXEC @sql
```

Or with out concatenate operator, you can use two single quotes around the keyword:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT word FROM #Parameter WHERE Name = ''word search''';
--PRINT @sql
EXEC @sql
```